# "Hint book" for arbitrary books (Rudin, Hungerford, etc.)?

Tags: discussion

I am planning on completing all of chapter 3's questions for baby Rudin. Maybe we could collaborate and write a hint manual for all of the chapters (and no rush, at all - it is user-driven). This would prevent dupes from showing often and also would encourage more to learn the subject (and self-study it) because of an actual book that gives hints. It will make the person think harder and definitely correct what they are thinking about in their head. It will clearly be community wiki.

Comment: [relevant](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9142/centralized-solutions-to-textbook-problems-considered-harmful/9151#9151)

Comment: Maybe instead we could post a hint book then @AlexanderGruber?

Comment: I have no opinion on this topic, just posting a related discussion for the benefit of other readers.

Answer (score 8):

While SE platform has some wiki elements, the project you are describing appears to be better suited to an actual wiki...  a place where  pages can be added and edited as much as needed, without   being  bumped to the front page.

And indeed, there is [Exercise Wiki](http://exwiki.org/mw/index.php?title=Main_Page) which includes exercises from several popular books (scroll to the bottom of the front page), but not from Rudin (yet?). Its format allows for both hints and solutions.

Comment: Link seems to point to unrelated website now